# How to extract awkward float representation with regex?

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to extract floating-point numbers from a string obtained from a NASTRAN solver file which has this form

`CBEAM        481       3    1002    1003  0.00001.000000-4.69-14`

I'm interested in the last three numbers: 0, 1, and -4.69x10^-14

I've tried multiple regex expressions up to now. I'm programming in Golang so the solution I'm looking for is in [regex2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). I managed to get thus far:

```
[-]*\d\.\d{1,4}[^\d\.]*[\+\-\d]{0,2}
```

The regular expression should look for the following:

- A minus sign at the beginning
- The first digit before the decimal
- Decimal digits, more is better
- Avoid a digit followed by a decimal point
- Awkward scientific notation if present

My proposed solution is extracting the first digit of the next decimal number and thus is only yielding the first and third numbers.

I'm not really sure how to manage to avoid the decimal and point and also look for the scientific notation. My negated expression is not getting the job done because I'm looking for digits towards the end again!

Comment: Which 0 and which 1 are you extracting? It's not clear with `first digit before decimal`, followed by `avoid digit followed by decimal`

Comment: @ctwheels I'm extracting   0.00001 and -4.69-14. You can test it out at https://regexr.com

Comment: P.S. You can't regex shove `x10^` into your string (not the way you're trying to match the data). But you can name the capture for easier string manipulation on the coding side.

Comment: Also, it really isn't clear what you're trying to do. I would suggest adding the extra examples you provided Emma in the comments under her answer to your question and elaborating on what you're trying to match. The third example doesn't make sense with your logic. Where does the `3.1` come from?

Comment: Don't! This is obviously a fixed width file, probably from Fortran, so parse it as such. Extract the fields by column, fix up any differences in the number format (like the missing `e`), and pass to `ParseFloat`. There's no use for a regex here.

Comment: @hobbs Yeap, you were right. It is a fixed width file. Thanks for the protip!